# Run a 15 amp motor on a 30 amp breaker?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have recently purchased a 220v 15 amp jointer ( 12/3 wire). The only 220v outlet that is nearby is my dryer.  The dryer is on a 30amp circuit with 10/3 wire.  Can I make an extension cord (say 10/3 wire) and run the jointer off the dryer outlet?

Comment: Is it 10/3 wire with both neutral and ground, or does it only have one of those?

Comment: Does the supply cable to the dryer have separate neutral and ground? Another way of asking is does it have a 4-prong plug or 3?

Comment: By any chance, is your garage wired with Multi-Wire Branch Circuits (MWBCs)? If so, adding a 15A 220V outlet may be easier than you think.

Comment: Can you post a photo of your dryer outlet please?

Comment: its three prong plug. that's why I bought a 10/3.

Comment: @TerrySimpson -- can you turn it off and post a photo of the inside of the receptacle box?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the code issues and/or real-world safety of running a 220V 15A device on a 30A circuit.

However, keep in mind that dryer (and range) receptacles are NOT designed for frequent usage. They are designed to sit untouched for *years* at a time. Where a regular plug & receptacle might get used a few times a day (and with cell phone chargers and other devices sometimes more often than that), the dryer cord/plug and receptacle may not do well being plugged/unplugged on a regular basis.

In addition, you need to make sure the dryer receptacle is a newer 4-wire receptacle - hot/hot/neutral/ground NEMA 14-30. Older dryers (or rather, older houses never upgraded) use a NEMA 10-30. It is code-compliant to continue using a NEMA 10-30 **for a dryer**. But you should definitely not use it for a new device. So if you have a NEMA 10-30 then, in addition to any other issues of 15A vs. 30A, etc., you should be upgrading first to a NEMA 14-30 receptacle and change the dryer cord to match and remove the neutral-ground jumper inside the dryer.

Also see: [What's a simple solution to have 2 NEMA 14-30 receptacles and switch power between them?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26310/whats-a-simple-solution-to-have-2-nema-14-30-receptacles-and-switch-power-betwe) for a discussion of using a switch between 2 receptacles.

Answer (score 0):

With a motor load you can put it on a larger breaker to prevent tripping on start up. Your extension cord should be 10 gauge because of the 30 amp breaker. You only need your 2 hots and ground for a 220v motor. At 15 amp your motor is a 2 or 3 horse and I would want to make it has thermal overload protection built in, if not I would be adding a overload unit to protect the motor with the setting at 17.25 amps or below.

Comment: The unit has a magnetic overload already on the machine, My problem is once I hocked the machine up to the dyer plug with a home made extension cord and turn it on, it smelt like something was burning.  I quickly unplugged the machine and now I'm scratching my head.  The extension cord is 10/3.

Comment: Are you sure it's wired for 220v is the mag a 220v or a 120v. The coil voltage stamped on it? The 10-3 should be fine I know these are probably things you looked at but we can figure it out.